# How to cancel an event created by Polymer

Tags: javascript, events, polymer

This seems quite straightforward. Normally we would do

```
e.preventDefault();
```

to cancel an event, where `e` is an event. However in this case I would like to cancel a `touchmove` event inside the [custom `track` event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#gestures) created by Polymer.

By inspecting `e.detail`, we can see that the `e.detail.sourceEvent` property contain the original `Touch` <s>event</s>. <sup><sub>*(Correction: It is a `Touch` object instead of an event. The question remains the same as how to cancel the original `touchmove` event.)*</sub></sup>

I tried to cancel it by the common method:

```
e.detail.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
```

Surprisingly it didn't work. `.preventDefault` simply doesn't exist for the event.

So the question is how do I cancel this `Touch` event? I'm trying to by canceling this event to temporarily make an element not scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I can think of is to fire all the necessary events at the end of the first event and then stopPropagation. Here is a prototype of the idea:

```
_firstEventThatWouldFire: function(e) {
  ... do some stuff
  this.fire('necessaryEvent1');
  this.fire('necessaryEvent2');
  e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents unNecessaryEvent3 from being triggered
}
```

Hope that Help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `e.detail.sourceEvent.cancelBubble = true` and `e.detail.sourceEvent.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Those don't work since `sourceEvent` isn't really an event at all. Instead it's just a `Touch` object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can call `e.preventDefault()` on touch events [now](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/pull/3693).